# time-sync.target takes 90 seconds on system loading

Tags: boot

My server is loading too long, so I started digging into optimization and typed `systemd-analyze plot > graph.svg`. [It shown me](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z16kp0a1t5i41y9/graph.svg?dl=1) that `time-sync.target` takes 90 seconds on system loading.

How to reduce this time?
Whole system loading time at now is 2 minutes, without that bug it will be 30 seconds.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/systemd/timesync.conf`? Please paste it into your question.

Comment: Problem solved when I with my server admin fixed image on screen and I see that Linux fstab trying load swap partition that no longer exists since some time. It takes =90 secs